# Covert a list to string

Tags: python

```
def to_str(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return lst
    count = 0
    while count <= len(lst):
        result = lst[count] + to_str(lst[1:]) 
        count += 1
        return result
```

This is my code and it doesn't seem to work 
The input is

```
to_str(['c', 's', 1, 0, 1, 0, 's'])
```

and I am suppose to get a string `'cs1010s'`

Comment: If you run `to_str([])` you get a `[]`. You want `''`. Also, you have a while loop but you return on its first iteration, so that's unnecessary. I think you want `str(lst[0]) + to_str(lst[1:])`

Comment: I am getting a Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly error @Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the list element to string before concatenating. Also, when the list is empty, then return empty string, instead of the empty list.

```
def to_str(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return ''  # return empty string
    count = 0
    while count <= len(lst):
        # convert lst[count] to string before concatenating
        result = str(lst[count]) + to_str(lst[1:]) 
        count += 1
        return result
```

However, there's lot of unnecessary code in your function. You should write it as

```
def to_str(lst):
    if not lst:
        return ''
    return str(lst[0]) + to_str(lst[1:])
```

Comment: good, So we can do it in just one line: `return str(L[0]) + to_str(L[1:]) if L else ''`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes, Python one liners are always nice and compact :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) to convert the non-string elements to `str` and [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to concatenate a sequence of strings:

```
def to_str(lst):
    return ''.join(map(str, lst))
```

**Edit:**

Since it seems like you want to solve this using *recursion*, it won't make sense (in this case) to use iteration (the `while` loop).

You will have to explicitly cast to `str` because some elements of the list are `int`, and you can't concatenate a `str` and a `int` using `+`:

```
def to_str(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return '' # if length is 0, return an empty string, so you can concatenate it
    result = str(lst[0]) + to_str(lst[1:]) # concatenate first element with the result of to_str(the rest of the list)
    return result

print to_str(['c', 's', 1, 0, 1, 0, 's'])
# cs1010s
```

Comment: Okay but I want to know what's wrong with my code @Christian

Comment: @user3398505 +1 your question because you wants to learn why your code not working instead just to get your assignment done...and good answer Christian.